# How to remove a personal Google account with the same address as an Apps account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account

I'm using Google Apps for example.com. Before doing so, my example.com email address was associated with a Google account, probably because of Picasa. Upon attempting to reset the password for my address ([google.com/accounts/recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery)), Google notes that I've got two accounts associated with my address: one personal from Picasa and one organisational from the administrator at example.com.

This causes all sorts of trouble, mainly that I can't associate the email address with a (Gmail) Google Plus account because "an account with that email address already exists".

How can I delete the personal Google account?

Comment: It's not possible to have two Google accounts with the same username. To  reset the password of a Google Apps account you should ask for help to the administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the [account deletion procedure](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32046)?

> To delete your Google Account, follow these steps:
> 1.Sign in on the Google Accounts homepage. (If you forgot your password, you can reset it).
>
> 2.Click Edit next to the "My products" list. If you don't see the Edit link, your account was likely created through an organization or
> company. To delete your account, talk to your domain administrator.
>
> 3.On the following page, click Close account and delete all services and info associated with it to delete your account.
>
> 4.Confirm your account deletion. To do so, you'll need to select these two options: "Yes, I want to delete my account," and "Yes, I
> acknowledge that I am still responsible for any charges incurred due
> to any pending financial transactions." (You can safely select the
> latter option if you haven't used any of Google's paid products, such
> as AdWords and Google Checkout, or if you have no pending financial
> transactions related to these products.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Gmail still complains that "an account with that email address already exists", so I suppose that was caused by something else.